# Largest power of $p$ which divides $F_p=\binom{p^{n+1}}{p^n}-\binom{p^{n}}{p^{n-1}}$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I would like to know your comments in order to obtain the largest power of the prime number $p$ which divides
$$
F_p=\binom{p^{n+1}}{p^n}-\binom{p^{n}}{p^{n-1}}.
$$

I proved the largest power that divided $F_2$ is $3n$.

Comment: Would you care to show any work as to why you think that is the largest power?

Comment: It seems wrong: Consider $p = 3$, $n = 2$  https://www.google.com/search?q=(2%5E5)%20choose%20(2%5E4)&oq=(2%5E5)%20choose%20(2%5E4)&aqs=chrome..69i57j6.8942j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=(%20((3%5E3)%20choose%20(3%5E2))%20-%20((3%5E2)%20choose%20(3%5E1))%20%20)%20/%20(81%5E2)

Comment: Do you know about Lucas' theorem?

Comment: @ThomasGrubb Put $$F_p=
\binom{p^{n+1}}{p^n}-\binom{p^{n}}{p^{n-1}}.
$$I proved it for $p=2$ that $3n$ is the largest power of 2 that divided $F_2$ .

Comment: @amcalde Lucas's Theorem says that both terms are divisible by $p$. By itself, this doesn't tell us whether the sum of the terms is divisible by $p^2$, for example.

Comment: @user357980 Do you have any idea for the true version of my theorem?

Comment: @ amcalde Yes. i know Lucas theorem, But I think it is not useful for my theorem.

Comment: @d.y I'm not sure if this paper answers your question, but if it doesn't, it may point you to useful literature. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.0252.pdf

Comment: For $p=3$ it appears to be $p^{3n+1}$; for $p=5$, $p=7$ and $p=11$,  $p^{3n+2}$.

Comment: As @user357980 pointed out, when $p=3$, $n=2$, the highest power is $7\neq 4\cdot2$.

Comment: @user357980 I think my theorem is true for $p=2$!!What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $p$ odd and $n\geq 1$,
$$
\begin{align*}
{p^{n+1}\choose p^n}-{p^n\choose p^{n-1}}&={p^n\choose p^{n-1}}\prod_{\substack{k=1\\p\nmid k}}^{p^n}\frac{p^{n+1}-k}{k}-{p^n\choose p^{n-1}}\\
&={p^n\choose p^{n-1}}\left[\prod_{\substack{k=1\\p\nmid k}}^{p^n}\left(1-\frac{p^{n+1}}{k}\right)-1\right]\\
&={p^n\choose p^{n-1}}\sum_{m\geq 1}(-1)^m p^{m(n+1)}e_m\\
&\equiv {p^n\choose p^{n-1}}\big(-p^{n+1}e_1+p^{2(n+1)}e_2\big)\mod p^{3(n+1)},
\end{align*}
$$
where $e_m$ denotes the $m$-th elementary symmetric polynomial evaluated on the set $\{k^{-1}:1\leq k\leq p^n,p\nmid k\}$.

For $p\geq 5$ we have $e_1\equiv 0\mod p^{2n}$ and $e_2\equiv 0\mod p^{n}$ (the first statement can be found on the [Wikipedia page for Wolstenholme's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem#Generalizations), the second statement is similar). Lucas' Theorem implies the largest power of $p$ dividing ${p^n\choose p^{n-1}}$ is $p$, so we conclude that $p^{3n+2}$ divides ${p^{n+1}\choose p^n}-{p^n\choose p^{n-1}}$. A larger power of $p$ is possible only if $e_1\equiv 0\mod p^{2n+1}$, which happens precisely when the numerator of the Bernoulli number $B_{p-3}$ is divisible by $p$. Only two primes with this property are known: $16843$ and $2124679$.

Comment: @Julian Rosen I could not understand how you obtained $e_m$? Why the set  $\{k^{-1}:1\leq k\leq p^n,p\nmid k\}$ is calculated by $e_m$?